# How does vysor create touch events on a non rooted device?

Tags: android, touch, android-source, vysor

This is the link of Vysor by Koushik Dutta - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm

It lets you control your Android device from a PC.
However, one thing that is bugging me since a long time is that it is able to create touch events on the phone even if it is unrooted.

After some of tinkering with the app and the chrome extension, I realized that he creates a separate process using the following way -

```
sh -c "CLASSPATH=/data/app/com.koushikdutta.vysor-1/base.apk /system/bin/app_process32 /system/bin com.koushikdutta.vysor.Main"
```

The `Main` class contains the code which passes touch events to framework via reflection.

The above code executes the `Main` class as a separate process which has `shell` as the user executing that process.

Still, as far as I know, the only way to create touch events outside your own app is if you're root.

Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: Given that it prompted me for `adb` debugging and validating the MAC address (for a device that *already* was set up on this machine for debugging), I assume he's using `adb` to pass over the touch commands.

Comment: He's using adb to pass the events to his `Main` class inside the apk.

Comment: Also, be it adb or anything, the root is always required.

Comment: I am referring to the `adb` binary that is part of the Android SDK. You do not need root to run `adb` on Windows, OS X, or Linux (for example, Windows does not have "root" in the same way that OS X and Linux do). I am under the impression that there are ways through `adb`, on a development machine, to send touch events to an app on a device (e.g., the way that `monkeyrunner` and such use). I don't know the specifics.

Comment: I was also wondering how this is possible on non-root devices. I just checked ps before and after installing,running vysor app from the chrome extension. As found by @omerjerk there are few shell processes running. I tried "am startservice" from shell but my service is not getting the shell userid. Can you tell me what am i missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've figured it out.

The thing is that the `shell` user is also allowed to create touch events all over the screen. When you do `adb shell` from a PC, having your phone connected to it via a USB cable, you're automatically assigned the user `shell`.

What he does is, he then starts his `Main` class as a separate process using this `shell` user. Now, the Java code inside that `Main` class has the same privileges as the `shell` user (because duh, it's linux).

And, in that class, he uses reflection to pass the touch events to the Android framework. The framework then automatically propagates the touch events to the windows.

Have a look at these two classes which I implemented in one of my own apps - [Main.java](https://github.com/omerjerk/RemoteDroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/in/omerjerk/remotedroid/app/Main.java) and [EventInput.java](https://github.com/omerjerk/RemoteDroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/in/omerjerk/remotedroid/app/EventInput.java).

But remember, since this `Main` class has to run in a separate process, it cannot access the memory of the app in which it is bundled. For that I have to use a socket mechanism to transfer the data. Even aidl can be used for this.